# Customising the JSON generated by EXT-JS

Tags: extjs

I am using EXT-JS 3.2.0 and I have an `Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel` backed by a `Ext.data.Store` object. The store has the restful flag on and uses `Ext.data.JsonReader` and `Ext.data.JsonWriter`.  It works great for retrieving data and populating the grid. However, when I add or update a record, the JSON produced for the POST/PUT has the data nested under a root field. This is not matching up with what the service I am calling expects. It wants a flat object. For example, when I add or update a record, the JSON produces looks something like this:

```
{
   "data":  {
      "name": "TEST",
      "id": "-1"
   }
}
```

But I need it to be

```
{
   "name": "TEST",
   "id": "-1"
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best approach but I ended up creating my own Ext.data.Connection object and making the request where I needed it, for example on the delete.  Not the solution I was hoping for but it works.